# PHP converter uma sentença com e comercial (&) em array

Tags: php, array

Tem uma função nativa do PHP que converte um QueryString em Array

Exemplo: `page=index&produto=115&usuario=2`

```
Array(
[0] => 'page=index',
[1] => 'produto=115',
[2] => 'usuario=2'
)
```

Eu sei que eu posso usar `explode('&' QueryString)`, mas lembro que tinha uma função que já identificava o `&` como um separador para o array.

Obrigado.

Comment: O PHP faz isso nativamente quando fazes um GET ou POST, e podes ir buscar os valores pelas chaves com `$_GET['page']` por exemplo, não é isso que procuras? senão podes explicar melhor de onde vem essa querystring?

Answer (score 2):

Como disse o @Sergio, o `PHP` faz isso automaticamente caso seja uma URL. Caso isso seja uma string qualquer, você pode usar a função [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php).

> `parse_str ( string $str [, array &$arr ] )` Converte str como se ela tivesse sido passada via URL e define o valor das variáveis.

---

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```